# Loop Process for each cell in Column

Tags: vba, excel

i have created the below code which is performing some tasks of filtering and then valookup based on a concatenated key.
Could you please help me to loop the code for each cell on Col Y?
The code work on Cell Y3.

This is my code:

```
Sheets("CAT Raw Data").Activate
Rows("1:1").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$Y$9633").AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:=Sheets("Exception Data").Range("C3")

  Range("A1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy

 Dim Data2 As Worksheet
    With ThisWorkbook
        Set Data = .Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count))
        Data.Name = "Temp"
    End With

ActiveSheet.Paste


Sheets("Exception Data").Activate
Dim e_name As String
Dim LValue As String


e_name = Range("A3")
LValue = "Your" & e_name


Segment = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(LValue, Sheets("Temp").Range("C:N"), 12, True)

Range("y3").Value = Segment
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Sheets("Temp").Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
```

Comment: Is it possible to have a dataset valid for this code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `For ... Next` to loop through each cell in column Y. For example this loops through Cells Y1 to Y100:

```
'[...]

Dim i as Long
Dim first_row As Long
Dim last_row As Long

first_row = 1
last_row = 100

For i = first_row To last_row
  e_name = Range("A" & i)
  LValue = "Your" & e_name
  Segment = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(LValue, Sheets("Temp").Range("C:N"), 12, True)
  Range("Y" & i).Value = Segment
Next i

'[...]
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do it. It will keep moving from A3 down until there is no more data and write to the same row but on column Y.

Paste the below into the bottom, replacing everything after the `ActiveSheet.Paste`:

```
Dim e_name As String
Dim LValue As String
Dim c As Range

With Sheets("Exception Data")

    For Each c In .Range("A3", "A" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
        e_name = c.Value
        LValue = "Your" & e_name
        Segment = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(LValue, Sheets("Temp").Range("C:N"), 12, True)
        c.Offset(0, 24).Value = Segment ' write to column A, offset by 24 to the right - column Y
    Next

End With

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Sheets("Temp").Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
```

Comment: Thank you for looking over the code.
The error i get is due to the fact that "Temp" does not exist as in my code, the page is created after in sheet Raw Data i filter by Cell C3 and paste the details filtered. in this page the vlookup is performed and after the result is displayed that page is deleted.

Comment: Basically, I need to repeat each time the filtering based on inputs on Col C as well. 
The cycle is that one page is filtered based on Col C, then information is pasted into a new sheet. The vlookup is performed in the new sheet and after we have the result, the new sheet is deleted. After this cycle, i want to go down with the next row, repeating the entire process of filtering and vlookuping.